# Innosetup: sspostinstall executed more than one time?

Tags: inno-setup, post-install

I try to execute an .exe in the `CurStepChanged` procedure at `(CurrentStep = ssPostInstall)`, the .exe is part of the `[Files]` section. It seems to me as if the `ssPostInstall` is executed multiple times – sometimes even before the files of the installation process are processed. Of course I could extract the .exe to a temporary folder but as I would like to understand the behavior it’s disappointing. The moment when the `ssPostinstall` step is reached seems to vary every time I execute and sometimes is reached more than one time. Am I missing something? Here is a part of my code:

```
procedure CurStepChanged(CurrentStep: TSetupStep);

var  ErrorCode : Integer;

begin
  if (CurrentStep = ssPostInstall) then begin
    if Exec(ExpandConstant('{app}\{code:getVersionSubdir}\licencing\haspdinst.exe'), '-i', '',SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode) then 
    begin
       if ErrorCode = 0 then      else
          MsgBox(SysErrorMessage(ErrorCode), mbCriticalError, MB_OK);
       end;
    end     
    else begin
         MsgBox('Did not work', mbCriticalError, MB_OK);      
    end;
end;
```

Thanks in advance

Chris

Comment: The `CurStepChanged` event for the `ssPostInstall` step is [`trigerred exactly once`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_5/Projects/Main.pas#L3890), right after the `[Run]` section [`is processed`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_installorder.htm) and the requested applications restarted. So it's something else in your script that makes you feel this way.

Comment: Add [`Log`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_log) call to your `ssPostInstall` code and run the installer with `/log=log.txt` parameter to check yourself.

Comment: @TLama So, Even if the section `[RUN]` finished with errors, the `ssPostInstall ` is trigerred anyway ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nesting and indentation in your code makes the issue non obvious, but hen the code is indented correctly, it becomes a lot more obvious that the nesting of your messages is wrong.

```
procedure CurStepChanged(CurrentStep: TSetupStep);
var ErrorCode : Integer;
begin
  if (CurrentStep = ssPostInstall) then
  begin
    if Exec(ExpandConstant('{app}\{code:getVersionSubdir}\licencing\haspdinst.exe'), '-i', '',SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode) then
    begin
      if ErrorCode = 0 then
      else
        MsgBox(SysErrorMessage(ErrorCode), mbCriticalError, MB_OK);
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    MsgBox('Too early? Did not work', mbCriticalError, MB_OK);
  end;
end;
```

Note the lack of `begin`/`end` in the `ErrorCode` `if` blocks meaning a single statement is conditional. The "did not work" message is in the `else` block of the `if (CurrentStep=ssPostInstall) then`.

How about something like this (air code):

```
procedure CurStepChanged(CurrentStep: TSetupStep);
var ErrorCode : Integer;
begin
  if (CurrentStep = ssPostInstall) then
  begin
    if not Exec(ExpandConstant('{app}\{code:getVersionSubdir}\licencing\haspdinst.exe'), '-i', '',SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode) then
    begin
      // Exec returned failure
      MsgBox('Did not work', mbCriticalError, MB_OK);
    end;
    else if ErrorCode <> 0 then
    begin
      // Exec returned success but non 0 error code
      MsgBox(SysErrorMessage(ErrorCode), mbCriticalError, MB_OK);
    end;
    // Else here if you want to do something on success
  end;
end;
```

The importance of tidy code :p
(And why I never miss out `{`/`}` and `begin`/`end` in blocks, even when not needed)

Comment: Ah, I think I finally got what *did not work* means :) Weird is that *sometimes*, but good catch!